# print () command and multiple items

Tags: lua

Some context, This is some of my first programming in Lua and I am doing it with QSC software.

```
local a = Controls.Flippy.String
local b = Controls.Flippy.Value
local c = Controls.Flippy.Position
local d = "  "
print(a..d..b..d..c)
```

This worked but is there away I can write strings in line with a variables.  Such as:

```
print("controls "a"  "b"  "c)
```

Comment: why would you name a references to a string, a value and a position a,b,c and d? those names are not very good.

Answer (score 3):

Same way you put the strings together--with `..`, the concatenation operator.

```lua
print("controls "..a.." "..b.." "..c)
```

It is also possible to use print with multiple arguments, though the spacing is often different (which may or may not be desirable):

```lua
print("controls",a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the strings as

`print("controls", a, b, c)`

You can choose not to put spaces in between if you wish not to.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to print multiple values in a line.

```
local name = "Frank"
local age = 15

-- simple, but not applicable for my example due to formatting:
print("My name is", name, "I'm", age, "years old")

-- using the concatenation operator ..   
print("My name is " .. name .. ". I'm " .. age .. " years old")

-- using string.format, best for complex expressions, capable of advanced formatting
print(string.format("My name is %s. I'm %d years old.", name, age))
```